# Windows command to get CPU and memory usage for all process at specific time say 10:00 PM MST

Tags: windows-server-2008

Kindly help me to get the windows command to get CPU and memory usage for all process (system and user process) at specific time say 10:00 PM MST..

This will very much helpful to troubleshooting day by day getting high spike to system.

I am troubleshooting this on windows 2008 server. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You could use WMIC, for example:

```
wmic cpu get loadpercentage /format:value
wmic os get freephysicalmemory /format:value
wmic os get freevirtualmemory /format:value
```

Just put these in a batch file, log the output and run it on 10:00 pm.

Edit:

Just thought about it, maybe you should use `tasklist.exe` or `pslist.exe` from the [sysinternals suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals)